# Extracting year which preceded with a month using Regex python

Tags: python, regex

I have thousands of datasets from where I am interested in extracting the year which preceded a month. For example:

In dataset 1: September 1980

In dataset 2: October, 1978

The regular expression that I wrote using https://regex101.com/:

```
^(?<month>)\w+(\1)\s[0-9]{4}$|(^(?<fmonth>)\w+,\s[0-9]{4}$)
```

It does do the job using the link. However, when I tried to use it in my python code, I was getting the below error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-216-a995358d0957>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Muntabir/nltk_data/corpora/cookbook/clean_data/text-classification_year(clean).py', wdir='C:/Users/Muntabir/nltk_data/corpora/cookbook/clean_data')
  File "C:\Users\Muntabir\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Muntabir\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Muntabir/nltk_data/corpora/cookbook/clean_data/text-classification_year(clean).py", line 76, in <module>
    year_data = re.findall('^(?<month>)\w+(\1)\s[0-9]{4}$|(^(?<fmonth>)\w+,\s[0-9]{4}$)', tokenized_string)
  File "C:\Users\Muntabir\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
  File "C:\Users\Muntabir\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Muntabir\Anaconda3\lib\sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Muntabir\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 855, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Muntabir\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 416, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "C:\Users\Muntabir\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 691, in _parse
    len(char) + 2)
error: unknown extension ?<m
```

I am not sure why it is causing this error. Can anyone provide me with an explanation with a possible solution? Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a valid **Python** regexp. You probably tested it on https://regex101.com/ with **PHP** selected (under "Flavor").

Comment: `r'\w+,?\s+[0-9]{4}(?!\d)'`

Comment: Hello Wiktor,
It works but it extracts multiple years from the document which I do not want. I want to extract the only year which precedes with the month and the line started with the month. This is why I was using "^" (cap) symbol before the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re

year = re.compile(r'(\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?\D?(\d{1,4})')
print(year.match('September 1980').group(3))
print(year.match('October, 1978').group(3))
```

Output:

```
1980
1978
```

Answer (score 1):

I really appreciate all of your contributions. But @Joan Lara Ganau's solution provided me with a guideline what the regexp could be. @Joan, your regexp is going to match if any year preceded with a month and a date. Also, it does not search for a comma and space. As I mentioned that I have thousands of datasets from where I exactly want to extract a year which preceded with a month. I was looking for the following format:

a.) Month Year
b.) Month, Year

Anyway, I found the solution to my problem set after doing a number of experiments. The solution is:

```
year_result = re.compile(
                    r"(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|"
                    "Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|"
                    "Dec(ember)?)(,?)(\s\d{4})")
```

Also, the match() method will also return **None** if the pattern does not get matched. In that case, using the group() method will throw an AttributeError. The error is something like None type object does not have a matching group(). So, I fixed it in the following manner:

```
def matched(document):                   
         year = year_result.match(document)
         year = year_result.search(document)
         if year is None:
               return '0'
         return year.group(14)
```

Now you can pass the text document from where you want to extract the year to the above function.

Thanks

Comment: Glad I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

A named capture group is: `(?P<name>...)` not <s>`(?<name>...)`</s>.

Use: `^(?P<month>\w+),?\s[0-9]{4}$`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/aKQMil/2)